# Codeigniter css in view

Tags: css, codeigniter, directory-structure

I added new function which is called "css_url". I set in constructor of controller, It works.
Besides, I want to reach in assets in view. In view directory I put themes, and each themes has own assets. How can I reach assets in view directory?

```
-view
--theme1
---assets
----css
----js
----images
-----f1.jpg





public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    // Temel veriler veri tabanından çekilecek;
    $this -> theme = "theme1";

    $this->config->set_item('css_url', $this->theme);
}
```

css_url("images/f1.jpg");

Comment: Best practice to place your assets,themes folder is under codeigniter root directory that is where is application and system folder.So that you can easily access it using `base_url()`

Let me know if you need any help further

Answer (score 0):

goto application/config/autoload.php and url helper like this...

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Now you are able to access assets folder in your view using base_url() function like this...

```
<?php echo base_url('assets/css/yourstyle.css'); ?>
```

Place your assets folder on root of your application...

```
application/
assets/
system/
```